# Zimbra is not working properly

Tags: dns, centos7, zimbra

A couple of days ago i tried this tool for a little project and it goes without errors for now, but the service looks *inactive (exited)* so this is what im doing actually.
Im using Centos 7 virtual machine on VMware and Zimbra open source 8.7.10. I read tutorials about setup zimbra, I make a dns name on the same virtual machine but Im not sure if this works good or I have to install another Centos for doing DNS server work.
I tested the DNS I made with Windows 8.1 (installed on my dektop machine) with *nslookup* adding ip on dns net properties and it got response. 
I cant enter on Zimbra web console, maybe Im missing something.

```
  [root@mail ~]# systemctl status zimbra
● zimbra.service - LSB: Zimbra mail service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/zimbra; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since vie 2017-06-30 11:43:34 -04; 19min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 834 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/zimbra start (code=exited, 
status=0/SUCCESS)

jun 30 11:42:03 mail zimbra[834]: Starting opendkim...Done.
jun 30 11:42:03 mail zimbra[834]: Starting snmp...Done.
jun 30 11:42:05 mail zimbra[834]: Starting spell...Done.
jun 30 11:42:10 mail zimbra[834]: Starting mta...Done.
jun 30 11:42:12 mail zimbra[834]: Starting stats...Done.
jun 30 11:42:23 mail zimbra[834]: Starting service webapp...Done.
jun 30 11:42:29 mail zimbra[834]: Starting zimbra webapp...Done.
jun 30 11:42:30 mail zimbra[834]: Starting zimbraAdmin webapp...Done.
jun 30 11:42:30 mail zimbra[834]: Starting zimlet webapp...Done.
jun 30 11:43:35 mail systemd[1]: Started LSB: Zimbra mail service.
```

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i can use zimbra. The error were 2, the first one was allowing port 7071 on Server side, the other was the DNS config, this last one is just pointing to Zimbra IP in DNS field. Even i can send mails to gmail what i think it was impossible, jaja.
Anyway thank you, but if someone have a good practices for zimbra Im all ears. I mean certificates for tls/ssl for clients believe its safe.
Cheers!